# Explanation of how the weak form is derived for 2D heat problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Given the following equation
[Strong form of the equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evu8I.jpg)
how does one arrive at
[Weak form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CYqi.jpg)

I am struggling to understand how the integration by parts is performed.